# search with ajax laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I need my project to have a search form, I tried with this code, but when I execute console it says:

> `POST http://localhost:8000/buscar 500 (Internal Server Error)`

then here is my view

```
<div id="qnimate" class="off">
    <div id="search" class="open">
        <button data-widget="remove" id="removeClass" class="closeSearch" type="button">×</button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar Noticias -  Articulos - Reviews"  id="buscar" onkeydown="keydownFunction()" onkeyup="keyupFunction()">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-site" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar</button>
        <div id="resultadoBusqueda" class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my controller

```
public function buscar()
    {
        $keywords = Input::get('keywords');
        $reviews = Reviews::where('estado','1')->take();
        $buscarReviews = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
        foreach ($reviews as $review) {
            if(Str::contains(Str::lover($review->nombre), Str::lover($keywords)))
                $buscarReviews->add($review);
        }
        return view::make('busqueda')->with('buscarReviews', $buscarReviews);
    }
```

here is the view which shows the information

```
@foreach($buscarReviews as $review)
    <div id="reviews" class="col-md-12">
        <a href="/review/{{$review->slug}}" class="link"></a>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="Imagenes/{{$review->logo}}" width="50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2>{{$review->nombre}}</h2>
            <div>{!! str_limit($review->descripcion, $limit = 150, $end = '...') !!}</div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

here is my js

```
var timer;
  function keydownFunction(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var keywords = $('#buscar').val();

        if(keywords.length > 0){
          $.post('/buscar', {keywords: keywords}, function(markup){
            $('#resultadoBusqueda').html(markup);
          });
        }

    }, 500);
  }
  function keyupFunction(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
```

I don't know what is the reason that it doesn't print the information required.

Comment: When you get 500 status code, you can see detailed error output in the log file (in storage folder). You could also set APP_DEBUG to true to see errors in the browser

Comment: The error comes from your controller. Make sure you included `Input`, `Reviews` and `Str` in your controller. You can also check the browser console to see the actual error.

Comment: i check console and i find say this `jquery-1.12.4.js:10254` and i checked and say `xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );`

Answer (score 0):

you are sending post request from ajax but in your controller you are trying to get that value using get, try this code

`public function buscar(Request $request)
    {
        $keywords = $request->keywords;
        $reviews = Reviews::where('estado','1')->take();
        $buscarReviews = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
        foreach ($reviews as $review) {
            if(Str::contains(Str::lover($review->nombre),   Str::lover($keywords)))
                $buscarReviews->add($review);
        }
        return view::make('busqueda')->with('buscarReviews',     $buscarReviews);
    }`

also remember to change in route like this.

`Route::post('buscar', 'yourController@buscar');`

Comment: yeah, i tried but still get `http://localhost:8000/buscar 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.12.4.js:10254` i dont know why